# React - error in useEffect(). does dat make everything on page go in infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks, use-effect

I've converted all my class components to functional components. Now, when I change some code in the IDE during development my page goes in an infinite loop. I'm almost certain one on my `useEffect()` hooks has an mistake (or missing) conditional firing variable. But it would take some time to figure out which one.

So, my question is. Is there an easy way to figure out which one is broken that would cause the loop. And would it also loop after build, or only in development?

As requested a code example. It is very basic since I have about 20 using this principle.

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

const Layout = ({ data }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // some jQuery stuff
  }, [data.myConditionalVar])

  return (
    <div>
     // my stuff
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you show us the code then we might be able to spot the source of the infinite loop. If you genuinely have no idea you could insert breakpoints into your code and step through it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, I've added some basic code. I cannot show you all since it would be an entire site :) And I don't know what is breaking it. But I think I'll play with breaking points first

Comment: Infinite update by `useEffect` end up with `maximum update depth exceeded` error with a stack trace that can be used to determine a cause. Are you sure you run react in dev mode?

Comment: Well, I'm not getting such feedback. I run my Gatsby.js project in develop mode. So I would presume I am. That could also mean `useEffect` might not be the source of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` gets called every time the second argument you pass is changed. In your case it is `data.myConditionalVar`.

So, I am assuming inside `useEffect` you are updating the `data` using jquery which forces React to call the `useEffect` again resulting in a never-ending loop.